# update EF under ADF in USIM in java card

Tags: applet, javacard, sim-toolkit

I am working on applet and I want to update  a FIle  (a LOCI file for example  : 0x6f7e ) under USIM  using SIM/UICC applet.

The first question is:  can I read/update EF under the ADF using SIM JAVA API  (using STK applet) ?

According to my reads (the 3GPP TS 43.019) The obvious answer is no, i am wrong did i miss somtehing that can let me read/update a file under the ADF using SIM applet ?

So i started working on UICC applet (release 6)  based  on the (ETSI TS 102 241) and  the stepping stone ([link here](http://simalliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/StepStonesRelease6_v100.pdf)) the ADF can be a readed/updated only by getting the ADF reference (getTheFileView) using the AID. but for an unknown reason I am having and UICC exception   (0003 : SECURITY_STATUS_NOT_SATISFIED ) in the update command (the selection goes well). The Applet is installed with full access and Admin Full access also (using GEMALTO tools).

you can find here the code that i am using  (in the applet init):

```
    AID adf_aid = new AID (uicc_aid, (short) 0x00, (byte) uicc_aid.length);
    ADFView = UICCSystem.getTheFileView( adf_aid,
             JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
```

on this part i also use the AID as buffer without creation of the AID object.

update on the STK menu access

```
    ADFView.select(FID_EF_LOCI);
        ADFView.updateBinary((short) 0, eraseLoci, (short) 0,
                (short) eraseLoci.length);
```

I tried almost everything that I thought about :

- select the MF before selection of the AFD.
- select directly the 7FFF

  and i  still having same exception, can you please tell what should i check ?   must I change the code, use another release (Jar file) ?    use a specific install parameter ? is there any other solution to update the files under  the ADF ?

i checked the AID value and its same put in the first record of  the EF_DIR (2F00).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get a resolution of this issue? I am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna try simalliance cat loader instead. it has privilege modification for FileView and AdminFileView.